# Is it possible to start the tests within one spec file?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I was wondering if is possible to run the test within one file. For example if I have multiple directories and I want to test just one folder then I need to set all file to fdescribe or fit. But if possible I could use just one file where I can set fdescribe which runs the test. Is this possible?